# How would I get the name of the class that has an inherited main method?

Tags: java, reflection, program-entry-point, entry-point

I have an Application class that is the base class for a ClientApplication. The Application has a main method that prints the name of the class that was defined to invoke the main method.

```
public abstract class Application {
  // Using this class as the entry point would output "Application"
  public static void main ( String... args ) {
    // Print the name of the class that is calling the main method
  }
}

public class ClientApplication extends Application {
  // Using this class as the entry point would output "ClientApplication"
  // main is inherited and can be invoked via the ClientApplication class.
}
```

I have tried to use an instantiated Object to get the name of the class like so:

```
public abstract class Application {
  public static void main( String... args ) {
    System.out.println( new Object() {}.getClass().getEnclosingClass().getSimpleName() );
  }
}
```

But that prints out "Application" no matter which class is defined as the class that contains the main method.

Comment: Do you need the method to be `static`?

Comment: Yes. I am going to use the main method, which has to be static, to instantiate the containing class and I feel using reflection is a better shortcut to rewriting code.

Comment: I have also tried using a `StackWalker` and a `Throwable` stacktrace

Comment: Static methods are not inherited, since they belong to the class rather than an instance.

Comment: What is the reason for doing this?  Trying to determine the caller inside a method is usually a sign of a flawed design.

Answer (score 0):

Use this and you will get the caller class name

```
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println(getCallerClass(2));
}

public static String getCallerClass(int level) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    StackTraceElement[] stElements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
    String rawFQN = stElements[level + 1].toString().split("\\(")[0];
    String className = Class.forName(rawFQN.substring(0, rawFQN.lastIndexOf('.'))).getName();
    className = className.substring(className.lastIndexOf('.') + 1, className.length());
    return className;
}
```

}

Comment: stElements has a length of 2
`java.base/java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace( /* file:line */ )` and
`Application.main( /* file:line */)`

Comment: If you are calling main method directly from Application class itself then it will be length 2, You need to call from other class right then the length will be greater than 2. You can also add condition to check length and then based on length decide what to retrieve from stack

Comment: That's odd, IDEA does not seem to behave that way.